# Disappeared comments

Tags: support, comments

There was a few (I last remembered at least 5) comments on the question I posted, suddenly disappeared and only left with mine. At least 2 user posted the comments. I seriously doubt they deleted all of it.

Comment: I think a mod regularly cleans up comments if there are too many of them, or if some of them are just chat.

Comment: @stevenvh, let me clean that up for you :)

Comment: I just saw that a mod (probably that damned Kortuk, fast Americans ;-)) has deleted *all* comments to an answer of mine. A bit drastic, though the discussion was at times harsh. Now other users can't judge anymore if the downvote I got was fair or not.

Comment: On [this question](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/32110/what-are-the-properties-of-an-n-bit-microcontroller) all but the highest voted comments were deleted.

Comment: @stevenvh, They should be able to judge if your downvote is fair based on the questions content, not on the opinions of others. If they are not qualified to judge the post without the support of others they should not be voting.

Comment: @stevenvh, the number of comments thing is a pretty standard cleanup. If there are more then 20 comments on any posts we are automatically notified to go perform cleanup on the post. This includes helping resolve disputes and removing comments.

Comment: @Kortuk - I can judge an answer by myself, but if I see a good answer with downvotes I'm curious what the downvoter's motive was.

Comment: @stevenvh, I think I just found part of what set of posts you were unhappy about having comments removed, these were removed because the issue was being initiated by a user whom we have had issue with and has received suspensions for such behavior. Having the noise of this user is not currently productive and we are acting on the comments, this is a special circumstance and should not be considered the norm, normally disagreements are left as long as they stay civil and on topic.

Comment: @Kortuk - Well, the comments are gone (though I still have a copy of them open in another tab here :-)), but the downvote is still there and it looks ugly. Almost a stigma. I remember I said the same about the revenge downvote Federico got a short while ago. With 47k rep I don't care about -2, but it's the principle.

Comment: @stevenvh, I can get you full logs if you need them, but it seems you have them.

Comment: @stevenh, I think only you (and mods and maybe others with mega-rep) can see the downvote. The rest of us just see +9, which is hardly a stigma or a sign of a bad answer.

Comment: Also, why so much worry about up and downvotes. I find I get the most votes for being quick with an easy answer rather than for giving a solid answer to a difficult (or specialized) question. Votes are not much of a guide to the quality of your answers --- and most of the regulars here, at least, realize that.

Comment: @ThePhoton - Ed Koch's signature is "How am I doing?". That's what a vote is for me. On the rare occasions I get downvoted my immediate reaction is "Why?" Not out of disbelief, but if people feel there's something wrong with my answer I would like to know what it is, so I can fix/improve it. I don't want to post bad answers. And yes, I have felt bad about a downvote which I thought was totally unfair, but that user is now in quarantine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moderators regularly clear off-topic/not contrustive/rude/out dated comments.

Your comments were probably left because they related to adding further detail to the question, ideally those comments are edited into the question as further detail and they are then deleted also. Lets focus on keeping the house tidy. Someone visiting the site will have better results with a clean question and answers, comments are great to get the best answers possible and occasionally there are a few of discussion that are worth keeping but they should be generally included in the related post.

Comment: I think those comment should be left there. The best practice in programming is always to not delete anything. Of cause maybe the cleaned up comment is still left in the db. Anyway, I would suggest that the comment be mark as archive, hidden by default, so to appear tidy. Then if the user chose to, they can still see it by expanding it. As for my case, those comment are specific instruction for me to correct my question, which I might want to refer back later on, but it's no way to be found now. So far I have not faced this in stackoverflow or other stackexchange sites

Comment: Btw, those cleaned up comments, are from you if I remember correctly :P

Comment: @faulty, useful information should be edited in. Some were me, if you improve the question I will remove them. If I see many comments asking for clarification you give I will remove the questions so that the clarification is at the top.

Comment: I do understand the rational behind removing those comment, but it's a weird experience. In a way you're like taking a way other's memory. Although those comment seems not useful after I've updated my question, but it serve as a reference for me in the future. I think suggestion for stackexchange to be able to archive it would be nice, and will fulfill both our requirement

Comment: @faulty, the comments mean nothing once you have answered them. by clearing them I increase the signal to noise ratio. Your extra details now show as the only extra comments on the post, they are of value. This is all semi moot as there would be no issue if the information was there in the first place.